# Client and peer role interchange in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Can a client become a peer in one transaction or block and vice versa for another or they are always totally different entities in a Hyperledger Fabric based blockchain?

Comment: Do you mean to understand the feasibility of hosting the client and the peer on the same machine?

Comment: No. I mean if a peer can have multiple roles?  Like for once it is endorsing a transaction, and later on proposing a transaction as client?

Comment: Yes it is possible